# How to make buttons to enter specific values?

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static string a = "a"; public static string b = "b"; public static string c = "c";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = a;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = b;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = c;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = null;
        b = null;
        c = null;
    }
}
```

I want to make a simple keyboard for a chat.
I started it with a small sample program in which there are only 3 buttons; Button a, Button b, Button c for a,b,c, respectively.
When I run the Program,I press Button a for a & then Button b for b (Now I want the Output in the form ab) but it first shows a and then on pressing button b it erases a and shows b.
I want to make more buttons like these to make a keyboard.
Basically,I want to print the letters stored in the buttons sequentially,but it erases the first one and then prints the next one..

Comment: Show us the code. Also what type of application are you developing? WPF, UWP, Windows Phone?  My guess is that you are not concatenating character 'b' to the output string

Comment: What? That is,  if You set text. You need at least to manage text (append, etc.)...

Comment: Sir dimlucas! I am working on Visual studio C#(Windows Form Application)
I am trying to upload the image or code

Comment: I have uploaded the code....

Comment: Also avoid using public fields. For this you should use properties. In this case the fields for the variables a,b,c can be made private and don't have to be static. Also they are don't really needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to create an on-screen keyboard is to use the buttons texts, except in special keys like backspace, enter, clear etc`.
That way all your text buttons click events can be handled with a single method:

```
private void KeyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text += ((Button)sender).Text;
}

private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
}

private void BackspaceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.SubString(0, textBox1.Text.Length-1);
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if this guy created button modifiers

Comment: @CallumLinington Not sure what you mean by button modifires, but I have used this exact method to create an on-screen keyboard, where each button had 2 different texts (one for capslock off and one for capslock on). Of course, the buttons I used was user controls designed specifically to be used in that keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

It erases the value because you are using `=` operator. Try to use `+=`

```
textBox1.Text += c;
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text  + c;
```

Also you can get a text value from the Button's [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158234(v=vs.110).aspx) property. 
And have only one [`Button.Click`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler, for each button.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    textBox1.Text = textBox1 + button.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in the comments before you posted the code you need to concatenate (a.k.a **append**) the character to the text box.

If you have a text box named `textBox1` doing this:

`textBox1.Text = 'a'`

will **replace** any text already written in the text box with the character 'a'

What you need to do is use the `+=` operator:

```
textBox1.Text += a;
textBox1.Text = b;
textBox1.Text = c;
```